# The pattern in the "src" property didn't match any files" React.js

Tags: git, reactjs

I am trying to upload a react-app to my github user page. I am successfully able to get my app running at my github user page url, but none of the images are showing up.

I have gone through both of these guides although I did not use create-react-app to make this web application.

https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#github-pages

I think the problem is because everytime I try to run 'npm run deploy', I get this cryptic error. "The pattern in the "src" property didn't match any files". I initially thought it meant the src folder in my app, but then I wasn't sure what the error meant by property. Next, I thought maybe it meant the src property in my images.

I am importing all my images from an images folder in the src folder, and referencing them using a relative path. In reaction to the error, I created a copy of my images folder to the public folder (did not delete the one in the src folder). Next, I changed the path of only one image to its file path at public/images. However, this approach did not work.

I am not sure what the error means, and I've spent a couple hours looking on Google and Stack Overflow trying to figure it out. I am able to run "npm run build", and all the images are reproduced in my public folder with the name they are being referenced with in the production version (for example, 09202a44a03f56132571bc2a6ad949d5.jpg).

If anyone has any ideas what the error means and how to fix it, that would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

I got this error because webpack output the build files to the "dist" folder, so when gh-pages looked for the static files in the "build" directory they weren't there. If you're also using webpack, try replacing

```
"deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
```

in package.json with

```
"deploy": "gh-pages -d dist"
```

Comment: this worked for me, tho i dont know why it goes there

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by running `npm run build` first as shown in the package.json file, to bundle into build folder as static page files:

```
"scripts": {
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
  },
```

then run `npm run deploy`
or edit the scripts:

```
 "scripts": {
        "deploy": "npm run build && gh-pages -d build",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
      },
```